# Right join vs left join, which table is left vs right?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, right-join

Given

```
select * 
from a
left join b
on a.id = b.id
```

is table `a` left and table `b` right?

Would that be equivalent to

```
Select *
from a
right join b
on b.id = a.id
```

because I switched `left` and `right` while flipping the `ON` clause? Or is `a` still `left` because it came first and `b` is `right` because it's the thing we're joining?

Thank you.

Comment: Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please don't ask or answer duplicate questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which table exactly is the "left" table and "right" table in a JOIN statement (SQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109704/which-table-exactly-is-the-left-table-and-right-table-in-a-join-statement-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  "left" and "right" refer to the ordering of the tables in the `FROM` clause.  So these are equivalent:

```
select * 
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.id

select * 
from b right join
     a
     on a.id = b.id
```

These two `on` clauses do exactly the same thing:

```
on a.id = b.id
on b.id = a.id
```

They do not affect the results at all.